# How to change icon on NSToolBarItem print

Tags: objective-c, macos

Is there a way to change icon on NSToolBarItem print? The setter for this is available via InterfaceBuilder but if I change it - it changes only in Interface Builder but not in working project. I tried to change it from code - but the same result. I have default print icon both cases. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this can not be changed what **you can create your own toolbar item** that will work for as Print.

Set new image for the toolbar button, and give Label and Palette Label, I have used My Print.
[image]

Now you need to hook  Print menu and Toolbar item's to a method, I have a method called `print` in the AppDelegate.

[image]